# Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following to check a few form inputs (will be part of a larger validation) but the console shows unexpected token for the first line.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.contactcheck').submit(function) {
        var abort = false;
        $('#name,#make,#model,#year,#email,#contactmeth').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val()==='') {
              $(this).addClass(' error');
              abort = true;
            }
        })
        if (abort) { return false; } else { return true; }
    })
});
```

Anyone able to point me in the direction of what is wrong? Looks valid to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the open parenthesis after function.

Replace:

```
 $('.contactcheck').submit(function) {
```

With:

```
$('.contactcheck').submit(function() {
```

On a separate note you could simplify your code if you do this:

```
return abort;
```

Instead of:

```
if (abort) { return false; } else { return true; }
```

Comment: Doh! Been staring at code way too long, thank you. This fixed that issue only to find out it doesn't add the class when no input has been made!

Comment: Happened to me couple of times, use a linter to avoid this things in the future. If you haven't I recommend you try VisualStudio Code. Please accept the answer if it help.

Comment: thank you, I can't accept until the time limit is up - any idea why the class doesn't get added? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Provide your html and Js here and share the link. https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `submit` expects a function. Function expressions look like this:

```
function () {}
```

So change your code to

```
$('.contactcheck').submit(function () {
```

It's the same as in `$(document).ready(function () { ... })`.